# How to set grouping by less than X, equal to X and more than X in a pivot table?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to use a pivot table to separate some data in 3 categories, less than X, equal to X and more than X, something like this:

```
╔══════╦═══════╦═══════╦══════════╗
║ Var1 ║  Var2 ║  Var3 ║   Totals ║
╠══════╬═══════╬═══════╬══════════╣
║ <4   ║     5 ║     3 ║        8 ║
║ 4    ║    10 ║     2 ║       12 ║
║ >4   ║     1 ║     8 ║        9 ║
╚══════╩═══════╩═══════╩══════════╝
```

The thing is that pivot tables doesn't allow me to set start and end in the same number, and when I use different the result isn't the desired but:

```
╔══════╦═══════╦═══════╦══════════╗
║ Var1 ║  Var2 ║  Var3 ║   Totals ║
╠══════╬═══════╬═══════╬══════════╣
║ <3   ║     5 ║     3 ║        8 ║
║ 3-4  ║    10 ║     2 ║       12 ║
║ >4   ║     1 ║     8 ║        9 ║
╚══════╩═══════╩═══════╩══════════╝
```

Is there a way to do this with pivot tables?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this with conventional pivot tables is to add a column to the source data and bring that column into the pivot table.

Comment: Can you expand on this?  What do you put in the added column?  Thanks.